# Java Generics : Unchecked cast from List<capture#10-of ?> to List<Object>

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a warning :
    `Type safety: Unchecked cast from List < capture#10-of ?> to List < Object>`

There is the call, `stock.getListDVD().getListDVD()` is an `ArrayList<DVD>`

```
jTablePanier=new JTableUt(stock.getListDVD().getListDVD(), DVD.class);
```

So i know the class it's a DVD.class

```
private ModelJTableUt model;    
public JTableUt(List<?> list, Class<?> classGen)
{               
    model=new ModelJTableUt((List<Object>) list, classGen); // <-- This line cause the warning, i convert List<?> to List<Object>
}

public ModelJTableUt(List<Object> list, Class<?> classGen) {
```

How can i resolve this warning without using

```
@SuppressWarning("unchecked")
```

---

Thanks a lot for your help. It save me many hours.
The solution is

```
 public JTableUt(List<? extends Object> list, Class<?> classGen){
    model=new ModelJTableUt(list, classGen);
 }

 List<Object> list;
 public ModelJTableUt(List<? extends Object> list2, Class<?> classGen) 
 {
     list = new ArrayList<Object>();
 //I construct a new List of Object.    
     for (Object elem: list2)
     {
         list.add(elem);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Just a hunch (dont have javac on hand): change `List<?>` to `List<? extends Object>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `List<?> list` to `List<? extends Object>` in :

```
public JTableUt(List<?> list, Class<?> classGen)
```

From [Java Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) :

> It's important to note that `List <Object>` and `List<?>` **are not
>   the same**. You can insert an Object, or any subtype of Object, into a
>   `List<Object>`. But you can only insert **null** into a `List<?>`.

Comment: Did you mean "Change `List<Object>` to `List<?>`"? As it is, this answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Answer Updated,  List<?> list to List<? extends Object>, thanks @PaulBellora

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't make sense. Your edit was unrelated to what I was talking about.